# 405 ERROR: Requested resource does not support http method GET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I know there are similar questions like this, but mine is unique. I'm running IIS 7. Initially I was receiving this error when POSTING/GETTING directly to the server in question. I read through answers on this topic and removed WebDAV from my config files, even though WebDAV wasn't installed on the server in question, and stopped receiving the 405 errors. The issue I'm having now, is when I access the server publicly and go through our companies firewall I'm receiving the 405 errors again. We have a public address that routes directly to the server in question. Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Does it work if you do a GET on the URL from the local box / not publicly?

Comment: Yes. the GET works as long as its sent directly to the box, meaning:
IPAddressOfServer/apiName/Get

But when we go through our publicly accessible IP I receive the 405 error, meaning:
publicIP/apiName/Get

The public IP is routed through the firewall directly to the machine. Also to note is the api log shows that we do in fact receive the message, IIS just keeps rejecting it for some reason.

Comment: Are you able to turn on IIS tracing? Perhaps the firewall is mangling the headers or something along those lines to cause the rejection.